# How to Get Oracle Database IP?

Tags: oracle, plsql, ip-address, sqlplus

How can I get the IP Address of an Oracle database?
I'm not the Administrator.

I'm using an Oracle application that has the access to that database.
How can I get the IP Address of the database?

Comment: One way is to check your tnsnames.ora file where you can find `(HOST=some_host_name/ip_address)` under the desired connection string. If IP address is there then you have got what you wanted and if host name is there, you can ping to that host name in command prompt to get ip address.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**From within SQL*Plus** ([Requires specific access rights to the network related functions](http://dbtricks.com/?p=159), so that might or might not be available for you as a non-administrator):

```
SQL>  connect / as sysdba;
Connected.
SQL> SELECT UTL_INADDR.get_host_address from dual;

GET_HOST_ADDRESS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
192.168.1.42
```

See also the [UTL_INADDR documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_inaddr.htm#i998289).

**From the shell** (if you are using tnsnames for resolving database names):

```
$ tnsping InstanceID
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=host.dbserver.com)(PORT=1521)) (CONNECT_DATA= (SID=ORCL)))
                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note the `HOST` output - this is the host name of your database server.

If your application is using `JDBC` to access the database, the host name is already part of the *JDBC connection string*:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@host.dbserver.com:1521:ORCL
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In either case, you can then use `ping` to get the IP address:

```
$ ping host.dbserver.com
PING host.dbserver.com (192.168.1.42) 56(84) bytes of data.
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways. Using `sys_context`:

```
SELECT sys_context('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS') FROM DUAL;
```

Or with `sys.utl_inaddr`:

```
SELECT utl_inaddr.get_host_address FROM DUAL;
```

Or the same commands using PL/SQL:

```
SET serveroutput ON
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line(utl_inaddr.get_host_address);
  dbms_output.put_line(sys_context('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS'));
END;
/
```